# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(): Silhouette performance algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, k-means, silhouette

I implemented kmeans algorithm in python and was trying to compute the [silhouette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) performance of cluster for various values of k.
Here are few variables for a small part of the dataset.

```
def avgdist(pt, clust):
    dists = []
    for elem in clust:
        dists.append(np.linalg.norm(pt-elem))
    return np.mean(dists)

def silhouette(data, clusts):
    s = []
    print("data-")
    print(data)
    for i in range(len(clusts)):
        for j in range(len(clusts[i])):
            clusts[i][j] = clusts[i][j].tolist()
    print("Clusters")
    print(clusts)
    for elem in data:
        a = []
        b = []
        print(elem)
        for clust in clusts:
            print(clust)
            if elem in clust: #Error in this line
                b.append(avgdist(elem, clust))
            else:
                a.append(avgdist(elem, clust))

        s.append((min(b)-min(a)/(max(min(b), min(a)))))
    return np.mean(s)
```

The output on terminal obtained is as follows-

```
data-
[[  0.   0.   5.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   7.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  12.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   7.]
 [  0.   0.   9.]
 [  0.   0.  11.]]
Clusters
[[array([ 0.,  0.,  5.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])], [array([ 0.,  0.,  7.]), array([  0.,   0.,  12.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  7.]), array([ 0.,  0.,  9.]), array([  0.,   0.,  11.])]]
[ 0.  0.  5.]
[[0.0, 0.0, 5.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

This is obtained along with the error in the commented line-

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Please help as I am not sure what that error means in my context. The similar questions gave me some idea of the error nature, but I believe is not applicable here.

**Edit** - I solved this question by changing in the line of error as-

```
.....
if elem.tolist() in clust: #Error in this line
    .....
```

Comment: You have been happy of obtaining answers on SO? Consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you try to evaluate at the line in question if a list of lists (clust) contains another list (elem), which results in an list/array of Truth/False values because the evaluation is done elementwise:
The code-line in question will evaluate along the lines

```
   if [True, False, ...]: #<- error here
       code
```

which will produce the error in question

instead of of holding lists of lists, convert/pack your data and cluster elements into lists of tuples and this evaluation will work.

Comment: Basically I want to test presence of one numpy array in a list of such numpy arrays. Is there a way to write a similar command equivalent to `if a in b` where a is numpy array and b is a list of numpy arrays. So finally, obtain a Truth value where all the coordinates are same.

Comment: You will need to repack the data to do this. something along the lines `[tuple(subl) for subl in listoflists]`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[  0.,   0.,   5.],
                 [  0.,   0.,   0.],
                 [  0.,   0.,   0.],
                 [  0.,   0.,   7.],
                 [  0.,   0.,   0.],
                 [  0.,   0.,  12.],
                 [  0.,   0.,   0.],
                 [  0.,   0.,   7.],
                 [  0.,   0.,   9.],
                 [  0.,   0.,  11.]])

clusts = [[np.array([ 0.,  0.,  5.]), np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])], [np.array([ 0.,  0.,  7.]), np.array([  0.,   0.,  12.]), np.array([ 0.,  0.,  7.]), np.array([ 0.,  0.,  9.]), np.array([  0.,   0.,  11.])]]
```

What about replacing

```
[...]
if elem in clust: #Error in this line
    [...]
```

by

```
[...]
if any([compa.all() for compa in elem == clust]):
    [...]
```

which *test presence of one numpy array in a list of such arrays.*

*Tested under Python3.6*

---

In summary

```
def silhouette(data, clusts):
    s = []
    print("data-")
    print(data)
    for i in range(len(clusts)):
        for j in range(len(clusts[i])):
            clusts[i][j] = clusts[i][j].tolist()
    print("Clusters")
    print(clusts)
    for elem in data:
        a = []
        b = []
        print(elem)
        for clust in clusts:
            print(clust)
            condition = any([compa.all() for compa in elem == clust])
            print(condition)
            if condition: #No error anymore in this line
                b.append(avgdist(elem, clust))
            else:
                a.append(avgdist(elem, clust))

        s.append((min(b)-min(a)/(max(min(b), min(a)))))
    return np.mean(s)
```

will print (only one comparison reported)

```
[...]
[ 0.  0.  5.]
[[0.0, 0.0, 5.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
True
[[0.0, 0.0, 7.0], [0.0, 0.0, 12.0], [0.0, 0.0, 7.0], [0.0, 0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 0.0, 11.0]]
False
```